# NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) not returning anything unless there is an error

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondatatask

Why aren't any results being printed?

I have been searching all over for an answer.  I've tried many different example blocks of code.  The print statements never fires unless an error is produced.  For example:  If I change the URL to "http" only with nothing else, I naturally get an error and it prints the error.  However, any valid URL produces no result in the print statement.

```
func post()
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.thebeerstore.ca")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "experiment"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Edit:  It works if I use a playground, but only in a playground.

Answer (score 0):

In your application's Info.plist file, add the property `App Transport Security Settings` and under that, add `Allow Arbitrary Loads` and assign `YES` for it.

With the above settings in your Info.plist, the app should be able to load your `http://` URLs as well

[image]

> Note: I would recommend not to use the above settings in your
>   production build, it could result in security issues.

Comment: I did that already.   By the way, I've been able to read all of the data from the beer store website and extract what I need, I simply can't begin the process of posting it to my database because of this issue.

Comment: Which issue are you talking about? print statement not firing?

Comment: Yes,  print("response = \(response)") produces nothing.  To be more precise, its as if it never reaches that statement.

Comment: Are you sure you have the Info.plist configuration correctly done? I could see the response string printed. I have provided the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: I could have sworn I had this working too on Friday.  It suddenly stopped working.  I created a brand new project after a few hours of frustration.  Yet, still, nothing, unless I intentionally cause an error with an invalid URL.   info.plist has <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: By the way, this is failing for me in an OSX command line tool as well.  There is no info.plist in that project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good explanation for this, but having finally stuck this same problem code into my primary project, it now works perfectly ok.  What changed???  Arrrrg!  How many hours wasted and I still don't really know why it wasn't working outside of my primary app.  Thanks for your help everyone.

Final code:

I do hope I can send over 100MB through a post request to be interpreted on the server side and store to the database.  Haven't done this before.  I'm a newbie.

```
func post()
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://bruceexpress.com/database.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(stores, options: [])
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
    {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Edit:  Yes, you can post a huge block of data.  Is this the correct way to do it?  ( Forgive my silly questions, but I am recovering programming skills left over from 2001.  I am a very outdated individual. )

Basically, what I have done is read all of the data on http://www.thebeerstore.ca, extracted every beer and its info and prices, and extracted every store and its info.  I interpreted this data, converted it into a large JSON block, and sent it to my server to be interpreted by a php script which will store this data to a database.

Sound like the right thing to do, or is there a better way to fill the database?